# How can I use merge command to merge 5 rows in this text file with 1 row in another text file?

Tags: linux, bash, merge

Summary I have a 1.txt with following order like this:

```
HLA-A1
HLA-A2
HLA-A3
HLA-A4
.
.
.
```

And another 2.txt with the order like (the line number="2/3" is constant, just the exon line is changed)

```
exon 1..2
/number="2"
exon 3..4
/number="3"

exon 6..7
/number="2"
exon 4..7
/number="3"

exon 9..31
/number="2"
exon 25..134
/number="3"

exon...
```

How can I use the `merge` command or another command to merge 5 rows in 2.txt with 1 row in 1.txt to have the final result seem like:

```
HLA-A1 exon 1..2 /number="2" exon 3..4 /number="3"
HLA-A2 exon 6..7 /number="2" exon 4..7 /number="3"
HLA-A3 exon 9..31 /number="2" exon 25..134 /number="3"
HLA-A4 ...
.
.
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Have a look at the tour, it will explain how to use the site.  Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn awk and get with the program, son:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR],$1,$2,$3,$4}' file1 RS="" FS="\n" file2
```

Output:

```
HLA-A1 exon 1..2 /number="2" exon 3..4 /number="3"
HLA-A2 exon 6..7 /number="2" exon 4..7 /number="3"
HLA-A3 exon 9..31 /number="2" exon 25..134 /number="3"
HLA-A4 exon...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste` command to merge files line by line.

Would you please try:

```
paste -d " " 1.txt <(perl -0777 -pe 's/(?<!\n)\n(?!$)/ /g' 2.txt)
```

1.txt:

```
HLA-A1
HLA-A2
HLA-A3
```

2.txt:

```
exon 1..2
/number="2"
exon 3..4
/number="3"

exon 6..7
/number="2"
exon 4..7
/number="3"

exon 9..31
/number="2"
exon 25..134
/number="3"
```

Output:

```
HLA-A1 exon 1..2 /number="2" exon 3..4 /number="3"
HLA-A2 exon 6..7 /number="2" exon 4..7 /number="3"
HLA-A3 exon 9..31 /number="2" exon 25..134 /number="3"
```

[Explanation]

- The `perl` script reformats `2.txt` by replacing a single newline
  with a whitespace. (There will be several ways to do that)
- The syntax `<(list)` is a `process substitution` and the output
  of the `list` is fed to the `paste` command as a second argument. The mechanism saves you from creating a temporary file.

Hope this helps.